# Updated to Mac OSX El Capitan, and my gitconfig permissions seem to have changed

Tags: git, osx-elcapitan

I just updated Mac OSX to El Capitan, and my .gitconfig permissions seem to have changed. I was trying to add a remote for a fork that I have:

```
git remote add upstream <repo address>
```

This results in the following error.

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

there can be several reasons for that.

Here are some options:

- Verify if there's some file called `~/.gitconfig.lock` or `.git/config.lock` 
  If that's the case just delete it.
- reboot and the lock should be released
- If none of these solves the problem you can always edit `.git/config` and set the upstream in there.
- rename the original file to something else and let git create a new one